# Creating and populating a page for multiple variables Swift 4.0

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift4

Im trying to figure out how to use a template (on the right) and every time I click a cell (on the left) it will change the value on the right view according to the cell chosen. So i.e Admin (administration, people can go here for help, long. and lat.) then it populates the view on the right with the according values. How would I accomplish this? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Where is the information saved? Do you get it from a database, or a file or even from a web service request?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. What you've diagrammed is pretty standard master/detail. Table views are data driven. You'd have a data model (probably an array of structs) containing the info for each cell. Your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method would use the indexPath that's passed in to look up the entry in your data array and then configure that cell. If the user taps on one of those cells, you'd push a detail view controller and pass it the struct for the cell the user selected.

Comment: You would not, under any circumstances, create a separate page for each variation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a model for each item in the tableview cell and pass it to the detailview controller and set that data in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an array "facilities" in the first ViewController.

```
var facilities: [Facility]
```

Now in the second view controller, define an object "facility".

```
var facility: Facility!
```

Now when you are pushing the second ViewController in the stack you can initialize it.

If you have the object of the second ViewController, use that object as objectOfSecondVC.facility = self.facilities[indexOfFacility]

Or if you are performing a segue, then take the destination and do the same thing as stated above.